# Code first from Database - Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id' but value actually is not null

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I try to add new record :

```
                 entity.Id = Id;


                _bdc.EquifaxAnswers.Add(entity);

                _bdc.SaveChanges();
```

and Id has exactly defined as primary key and Id in code has value ( unique for table).
And EF create sql code for add record:

```
 INSERT [dbo].[EquifaxAnswers]([FileName], [dtSend], [dtDateTime], [RecordsAll], [RecordsCorrect], 
[RecordsIncorrect], [ResendedId], [dtEmailAbout], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, @3, @4)
```

And as we can see there Id does not exist, so `_bdc.SaveChanges();`create Exception:

> Failed in 25 ms with error: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'Equifax.dbo.EquifaxAnswers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Primary key definition:

```
    public partial class EquifaxAnswers
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
```

Why EF don't add `Id` to INSERT and how to resolve this problem ?

**UPD:**
Table definition script in database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EquifaxAnswers](
[Id] [int] NOT NULL,
[FileName] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
[dtSend] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[dtDateTime] [datetime] NULL,
[RecordsAll] [int] NULL,
[RecordsCorrect] [int] NULL,
[RecordsIncorrect] [int] NULL,
[ResendedId] [int] NULL,
[dtEmailAbout] [datetime] NULL,
[StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
[EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_EquifaxAnswers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

This means that EF is not expecting the database to generate the `Id` field, and that you should specify the `Id` field yourself.

If you want the database to generate the `Id` field automatically, then alter the column to be an `IDENTITY` type, and change the code to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity`

Comment: I specify the Id field by myself - but EF even not include this field in INSERT - my question is about this !

Comment: And more of this - I have tryed DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity too - the same exception ...

Comment: are you sure EF model is up to date? looks like EF model isnt updated and its still using Identity.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro - absolutely sure, because it was always "None" - as I sad - I use Code First from Database - so I cannot change database stucture, I should use what I have

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<EquifaxAnswers>()
            .Property(a => a.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

If this doesn't work - just ***uninstall*** and ***install again all EF packages*** ( I don't know why - but this is work for me) for all dependent projects , latest stable version of course.

**Reasons:**

By convention, EF will assume that ***primary key*** properties are ***automatically generated***. So we need to say EF that we will do it by our code. However,this is not clear why doesn't work DataAnnotations like this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

but fluent API is working well. Perhaps the reason is that I use both.

Comment: The fix for me was to add [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)].